# Keep getting conflicts when installing python, flask and google cloud bigquery

Tags: python, flask, conda

I have this env.yml

```
name: env-app
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - google-cloud-bigquery=3.12.0
  - flask=3.0.*
  - python=3.12.*
```

If I run `micromamba env create --file environment.yml` I get this output:

```
conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
pkgs/main/osx-arm64                                           No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/r/osx-arm64                                              No change
error    libmamba Could not solve for environment specs
    The following packages are incompatible
    ├─ google-cloud-bigquery 3.12.0**  is installable and it requires
    │  ├─ pandas >=1.1.0  with the potential options
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.1.3|1.1.4|...|2.0.3] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.1.3|1.1.4|...|2.1.1] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.3.4|1.3.5|...|2.1.1] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 *_cpython, which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.3.4|1.3.5|...|2.0.3] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 *_cpython, which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.3.4|1.3.5|...|2.1.1] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 *_cpython, which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.5.1|1.5.2|...|2.1.1] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 *_cpython, which can be installed;
    │  │  ├─ pandas 2.1.1 would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.12.0rc3,<3.13.0a0 *_cpython but there are no viable options
    │  │  │     ├─ python 3.12.0 would require
    │  │  │     │  └─ python_abi 3.12.* *_cp312, which can be installed;
    │  │  │     └─ python 3.12.0rc3 would require
    │  │  │        └─ _python_rc, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
    │  │  ├─ pandas [1.3.5|1.4.1|...|2.1.1] would require
    │  │  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │  │  └─ pandas [1.5.2|1.5.3|2.0.3|2.1.1] would require
    │  │     └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │  └─ shapely >=1.8.4,<2.0dev  with the potential options
    │     ├─ shapely [1.8.4|1.8.5] would require
    │     │  └─ python_abi 3.10.* *_cp310, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    │     ├─ shapely [1.8.4|1.8.5] would require
    │     │  └─ python_abi 3.8.* *_cp38, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    │     ├─ shapely [1.8.4|1.8.5] would require
    │     │  └─ python_abi 3.9.* *_cp39, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    │     ├─ shapely 1.8.5 would require
    │     │  └─ python_abi 3.11.* *_cp311, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    │     ├─ shapely 1.8.4 would require
    │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │     ├─ shapely 1.8.4 would require
    │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
    │     └─ shapely 1.8.4 would require
    │        └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
    └─ python 3.12.*  is not installable because there are no viable options
       ├─ python 3.12.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
       ├─ python 3.12.0, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
       └─ python 3.12.0rc3, which cannot be installed (as previously explained).
critical libmamba Could not solve for environment specs
```

Comment: You're asking for specific versions of those software packages that simply can't be used together.  What actual answer are you hoping for here?

Comment: @JohnGordon oh I see so I just needed to downgrade to   - python=3.11.0 and now it works since that's the only package supported by all dependencies